# Parsing CDATA from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, cdata

This is my first post and I'm sorry if I'm doing it wrong but here we go:

I've been working on a project that should scrape values from a website. The values are variables in a javascript array. I'm using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and it works with the normal scripts but not the one stored in CDATA-blocks. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to scrape data within the CDATA-block. Unfortunately, all the help I could find was for XML-files and I'm scraping from a HTML file.

The javascript I'm trying to scrape is a follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var data = [{"value":8.41,"color":"1C5A0D","text":"17/11"},{"value":9.86,"color":"1C5A0D","text":"18/11"},{"value":7.72,"color":"1C5A0D","text":"19/11"},{"value":9.42,"color":"1C5A0D","text":"20/11"}];
//]]>
</script>
```

What I need to scrape is the "value"-variable in the var data.

The problem was that I tried to replace the CDATA string on an object.
The following code works perfectly :-)

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$lines = file_get_contents('http://www.virtualmanager.com/players/7793477-danijel-pavliuk/training');

$lines = str_replace("//<![CDATA[","",$lines);
$lines = str_replace("//]]>","",$lines);

$html = str_get_html($lines);

foreach($html->find('script') as $element) {
    echo $element->innertext;
}
```

I will provide you with more information if needed.

Comment: Buffer the HTML text before passing it to the parser, and search-and-replace to remove the `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` constructs. They're completely pointless and have been for years.

Comment: Also: you have weird spaces in the example URL. Is that a typo? Because the problem just could be you can't load the page at all. That is, does `$html->find('script')` even find *anything*?

Comment: That was a typo and I have fixed it now. I have tried removing the CDATA but I get this error subsequent: "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in..."

I have updated the post with what I'm doing now.

Comment: Why are you trying to call `str_replace()` on a HTML DOM object? What I meant is, download the HTML into a string (using `file_get_contents()` or curl), then search-and-replace that string, and **only then** parse that string into HTML, using `str_get_html()` instead of `file_get_html()`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It seems to work now :-)

Comment: Right, I'll just answerify the comments.

Answer (score 2):

A decent HTML parser shouldn't require Javascript to be wrapped in a `CDATA` block. If they're throwing it off, just remove them from the HTML before parsing, doing something like this:

1. Download the HTML file into a string, using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) if your host disabled HTTP support in that function.
2. Get rid of the `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` bits using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
3. Parse the HTML from the cleaned string using Simple DOM's `str_get_html()`
4. Process the DOM object as before.